# Vert.x: Handle Rabbitmq consumer backpressure without dropping new messages

Tags: java, rabbitmq, rx-java, message-queue, vert.x

When you have more incoming messages than you can handle. A solution is to limit the internal queue size:

```java
// Limit to max 300 messages
QueueOptions options = new QueueOptions()
  .setMaxInternalQueueSize(300);

RabbitMQClient client = RabbitMQClient.create(vertx, new RabbitMQOptions());

client.basicConsumer("my.queue", options, res -> {
  if (res.succeeded()) {
    System.out.println("RabbitMQ consumer created !");
    RabbitMQConsumer mqConsumer = res.result();
    mqConsumer.handler((RabbitMQMessage message) -> {
      System.out.println("Got message: " + message.body().toString());
    });
  } else {
    res.cause().printStackTrace();
  }
});
```

The problem is when the intenral queue queue capacity is exceeded, the new message will be simply **dropped**.

How to handle back-pressure without losing any message?

Answer (score 1):

I recently used `client.basicQos()` function to **limit message consumption from rabbit** and it's working smoothly.

The **first argument** of this function determine the **number of prefetched messages** stays with your consumer (or the whole channel), so it should work like an internal queue size, but without fetching and discarding messages.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke `mqConsumer.pause()` when you start processing a message then `mqConsumer.resume()` when you've done processing it. You should always do this when your processing is not synchronous.

https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-rabbitmq-client/java/#_consume

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I won't do that manually. There is vert.x `pipeTo` that is meant to do that for us but I can't make it work. Do you have an idea? Also I'm using rxjava, some maybe converting to flowable would help?  thanks

Comment: Sadly, the Vertx RabbitMQ consumer API is designed this way : "When the intenral queue queue capacity is exceeded, the new message will be simply dropped." (https://vertx.io/blog/eclipse-vert-x-rabbitmq-client-gets-a-new-consumer-api/#backpressure)